# Error in server connections

Tags: c#, sockets, communication, tcpclient, networkstream

I'm now trying to work with server. I have this code:
[image]

I'm starting 'HandleCC' method in thread with 'ParametrizedThreadStart'. I'm trying connection on '127.0.0.1'. I can connect. When I'm connected, 1st breakpoint is good, second too, but than code stops. (Console is still running, but no one from following breakpoints break's the code.)
Pleas help me, and sorry for my english.

**Full code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Threading;
namespace MTSP
{
class Comunication
{
    private TcpListener listener;
    private Thread thread;
    public Comunication()
    {
        this.listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 20345);
        this.thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ListenLoop));
        this.thread.Start();
    }
    private void ListenLoop()
    {
        this.listener.Start();
        while (true)
        {
            TcpClient client = this.listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread tr = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(this.HandleCC));
            tr.Start(client);
        }
    }
    private void HandleCC(object client)
    {
        TcpClient cli = (TcpClient)client;
        NetworkStream stream = cli.GetStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bytesread = 0;
        string mess = "";
        StringBuilder compmess = new StringBuilder();
        while (true)
        {
            bytesread = 0;
            try
            {
                bytesread = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            }
            catch
            {
                break;
            }

            compmess.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(buffer, 0, bytesread));
            string a = compmess.ToString();
            string g;
        }
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(compmess.ToString());
        cli.Close();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: How do you create `client`? What server are you connecting to? The most likely reason `Read()` doesn't return is that the server doesn't send any data. And the way you're using `catch` and `break` seems to be very wrong. Also, could you post your code as text, not a screenshot?

Comment: It doesn't stop, it blocks.  Send something.

Comment: @user35443, okay, would you mind answering the other questions too?

Comment: I'm connecting on 127.0.0.1 (me), and how did I created the client? You can see it in code.
@hans passant: What?

Answer (score 0):

In any client-server application you need both a client and a server. You wrote the server.
Here is an example of a client (this was tested and works with your code as the server):

```
    TcpClient client = new TcpClient("localhost", 20345);
    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

    while (true)
    {
        string message = Console.ReadLine();
        Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);  
        // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
        stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
    }

    stream.Close();
    client.Close();
```

Put this client in a separate console application, then:

- start the server
- then start the client in a new Visual studio instance, or start the exe
- type something in the client console window
- next it will go through your step of updating the `StringBuilder` you are using.

Comment: Well, than why it's your client not working? If it's working for me than it means it's not a code issue, might be a setting of some kind.

Comment: My client works, but my server does not works. But is possible that my firewall is blocking the port.